# Got "function missing required argument 'month' (pos 2)" error while adding a DateField to models.py

Tags: python, django

I am a Django beginner and I am trying to make a Biography app, I am following the official django documentation for learning the framework. So when I create a DateField in models.py as it was shown in docs, I got an error while I ran the server it says "function missing required argument 'month' (pos 2)"
what should I do? Please help

```
#models.py
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime
# Create your models here.

TYPE = (
    ('politician','POLITICIAN'),
    ('poet','POET'),
    ('author','AUTHOR'),
    ('actor','ACTOR'),
    )


class About(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200, default='')
    context = models.CharField(max_length = 200, default='')
    born_on = models.DateField('Born on')
    died_on = models.DateField( 'Died on')
    main = models.TextField(default='')
    category = models.CharField(choices = TYPE , default = 'poet', max_length = 10)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, default='', upload_to='static')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.created_on >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: Umm... it looks like you meant `born_on = models.DateField(label='Born on')`? (on a side note - you might also want to make both your DateField's nullable and blankable - as you may not always know when someone was born or died and people currently alive won't have a death date...)

Comment: Error shoots, unexpected  keyword argument 'label'

Comment: I bet the error is not in the model definition, but somewhere else. It would be easier to attach the full traceback

Comment: Ahh... yes... my bad... it's `verbose_name` as Bappy0X has pointed out in the answer below...

Comment: It worked by adding verbose_name, Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're attempting to declare a name for your DateField, but not using the `**options` set by django. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#datefield).

**Although I don't believe these are entirely purposeful for you - so you can just remove them.**

You can still use a `verbose_name`, if you choose:

```
born_on = models.DateField(verbose_name=('Born on'))
died_on = models.DateField(verbose_name=('Died on'))
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. In Django the declaration `born_on = models.DateField('Born on')` is perfectly legal, and even encouraged by the documentation.